# parse json file using gson/jackson java API

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

I am a new bee to both JSON and GSON. My JSON structure is as mentioned below and i am using gson library to parse the json object and retrieve the values I am getting all null values from the getters. Can anyone help me on this.

JSON file:

```
{
   "Samples":[
      {
       "Id":"XX",
       "SampleId":"XX",
       "Gender":"XX"
       }
     ]
}
```

Java-gson code:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(/mnt/ftp/sample.json));
//convert the json string back to object
patientObj = gson.fromJson(br, PatientJson.class);
patient_id=patientObj.getId();
sample_id=patientObj.getSampleId();
gender=patientObj.getGender();
```

Patient JSON class:

```
public class PatientJson {
    String id,sampleId,gender;
//with all the three getter and setters.
}
```

Comment: Show your PatientJson class

Comment: @user3746601 I am not too sure, but check the character capitalisation. Ie if string is `id` make sure JSON is also `id` not `Id`

Comment: Can any one help me with this problem. Either using gson or jackson API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it will help you..!

```
    JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(readFromFile());  
    JSONArray array= jsonObject.getJSONArray("Samples");  

        JSONObject json=array.getJSONObject(0);  
        PatientJson patient=new PatientJson();  

        patient.setId(json.get("Id"));  
        patient.setSampleId(json.get("SampleId"));  
        patient.setGender(json.get("Gender"));  

 private String readFromFile(){
String ret = “”;

try {
InputStream inputStream = openFileInput("yourFile");

if ( inputStream != null ) {
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
String receiveString = “”;
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
}

ret = stringBuilder.toString();

inputStream.close();
}
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
Log.e(TAG, “File not found: ” + e.toString());
} catch (IOException e) {
Log.e(TAG, “Can not read file: ” + e.toString());
}
return ret;

}
```

Comment: What should be the data type of "your_jsondata". My requirement is to read the JSON file using stream reader(BufferedReader).

Comment: @user3746601 ,Read all data from your JSON file and set into a String then pass that string in JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject("your_jsondata");

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your `PatientJson` as below

```
public class PatientJson {
String Id, SampleId, Gender;
//with all the three getter and setters.
}
```

Basically the name of the variables should be same as you getting in json or you have to map your variables to the json params using `SerializedName` [REF](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2.3/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html) as below

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
public class PatientJson {
@SerializedName("Id")
String id;
@SerializedName("SampleId")
String sampleId;
@SerializedName("Gender")
String gender;
//with all the three getter and setters.
}
```

To get data from your sample json you need to do the following

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(/mnt/ftp/sample.json));
  //convert the json string back to object
    Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<PatientJson>>() {}.getType();
    List<PatientJson> patientList = gson.fromJson(br, listType);
```

Comment: I tired this but still getting null values through getters. DO i need to access the values through getters or some other way?

Comment: What is the "Type" object here? To import i could see many different options. And also jsonObject.get("Samples").getAsJsonArray() seems to be incorrect.  jsonObject cannot be resolved.

Comment: Can you also tell me What is the "Type" object here? Which class should i import?

Comment: Type is basically java.lang.reflect.Type;  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Type.html

Comment: patientList is coming as null. I think the PatientJson class structure is still not correct.

Comment: Can you please get the full string from BufferedReader and print to make sure file reading proper

Comment: output from the buffereader as follows:{
      "Samples":[
         {
          "Id":"XX",
          "SampleId":"XX",
          "Gender":"XX"
          }
        ]
   }

Comment: Should i consider the input JSON datatype as Samples array instead of strings of id.sampleid,gender?

Comment: If you remove the sample key above code should work. Basically aray of PatientJson in your test file